# Php Form is not submitting the values

Tags: php

Kindly check the code,where i am wrong in this.Form is not submitting the values.Page is refreshing but not posting the values.I don't know what is happening.Pls check the code and identify the mistake.i had also used this code on another application as well.it is working there but not here

```
<?php
    if ($username && $userid) {
        echo "you are already logged in as $dbuser.<a href='w-post.php'> Click here to go to Post area</a>";
    }

    else {
        $form = "<form method=post action=123.php autocomplete=off enctype=multipart/form-data>

    <table width=759 border=1>
        <tr>
            <td width=749>
                <table width=756 border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3 bgcolor=#d9d9d9>
                            <div align=center class=style1><font color=#003366>PERSONAL INFORMATION</font></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=196>
                            <div class=label-text>Email Address</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width=297>
                            <div class=accountboxes><input type=text class=accounttextboxes id=txtemail name=txtemail
                                                           size=50/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width=241>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=196>
                            <div class=label-text>Password</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width=297>
                            <div class=accountboxes><input type=password class=accounttextboxes id=txtpass name=txtpass
                                                           size=50/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width=241>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=196></td>
                        <td width=297><input name=submit type=submit id=submit value=submit/>

                        <td width=241>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>";

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $user = $_POST['txtemail'];
            $pass = $_POST['txtpass'];
            if ($user) {
                if ($password) {
                    $password = md5($pass);
                    //echo $epassword;
                    $query   = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where email='$user'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrows == 1) {
                        $row      = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                        $id       = $row['id'];
                        $dbuser   = $row['name'];
                        $dbpass   = $row['password'];
                        $activate = $row['activation'];
                        if ($password == $dbpass) {
                            if ($activate == '1') {
                                $_SESSION['name']  = $dbuser;
                                $_SESSION['id']    = $id;
                                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                                header('location:forms.php');
                                exit();
                            }
                            else {
                                $error_account = 'Your Account is not activated yet';
                            }
                            echo $form;
                        }
                        else {
                            $error_pass = 'You entered an incorrect password';
                        }
                        echo $form;
                    }

                    else {
                        $error_email = 'Email Address not found';
                        echo $form;
                    }

                }

                else {
                    $enter_pass = 'Enter your password';
                    echo $form;
                }

            }
            else {
                $enter_email = 'Enter email address';
                echo $form;
            }

        }

        else {
            echo $form;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Some tips: **1.)** Use quotes around HTML attributes! **2.)** Don't use $_POST variables directly in your query, better use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or/and even more better: use PDO or MySQLi! **3.)** Where are `$username` and `$userid` coming from?

Comment: $username and $userid are in sessions

Comment: But they aren't global! Use `$_SESSION['variable-name']`

Comment: i used the same but i put them in variale $username=$_$_SESSION['variable-name']

Comment: Also, don't use tables for layout. Use HTML and CSS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You say you read the values from the `$_SESSION` array and assign these to `$username` etc., but where? Presumably you are also starting the session earlier in the code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOur code would be much simpler if you do it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $error = 0;
 $errorMessages = array();
 $user = $_POST['txtemail'];
 $pass = $_POST['txtpass'];
 if (!$user) {
  $errors++;
  $errorMessages[] = "Please enter your email address";
 }
 ...//rest of the form check
 if($errors == 0) {
  //do what you want with the data
 }
}
```

So you don't have that many brackets and else.

Comment: You could also leave out the $errors variable and in the end check for the size of $errorMessages like so: `if( count($errorMessages) === 0 ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You should quote all the attribute values such as `post`, `123.php` etc. throughout your HTML to be safe. Otherwise (assuming you are using HTML and not XHTML - where quoted strings are mandatory) any invalid characters will invalidate the HTML and your code might break, which is certainly one thing that could be happening with your code.

Using HEREDOC syntax:

```
$form = <<<EOD
<form method="post" action="123.php" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="759" border="1">
  <tr>

<!-- Rest of HTML code -->

EOD;
```

Comment: That answer is incorrect. The HTML5 specs allows for authors to omit quotes entirely in attribute names. You only need it if you have a space or an `=` inside of your attribute.

Comment: @Truth You mean, "omit quotes around attribute values". Which is why I state "Otherwise ... any invalid characters will invalidate the HTML". Invalid characters being characters that need to be quoted. _Browsers_ will break on slashes etc. also.

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM: THIS ISN'T A GIMME TEH KODEZ SITE HE'S HELPING YOU HELP YOURSELF. ALSO, PLEASE DON'T WRITE IN CAPITAL LETTERS, IT'S ANNOYING.

Comment: You appear to be using an XHTML DOCTYPE. In this case quoted attribute values are mandatory in order to validate. I assume that since you have accepted an answer, your immediate probelm is now resolved?

Comment: no no i didnt pls explain XHTML DOCTYPE thing.Explain more pls

Comment: You have marked up your document as XHTML (as opposed to HTML). XHTML is the formulation of HTML using XML. Consequently it follows XML rules. In XML attribute values must be quoted. Whether you are actually serving your document as XHTML, or as text/html, is another matter.

Comment: Also note that this statement: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` (at the top of your code) excludes E_NOTICE messages from being reported. During development is a good idea to report these (it might help to solve your current problem). So change this to `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. However, I would also show E_STRICT messages as well... `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`. [PHP Manual on error_reporting()](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)